# Elastic search query not resulting as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Having elastic search query as below -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query": "*Hanry Oliver 45354*",
        "fields": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName",
          "customerNo"
        ],
        "default_operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in one record which is correct.
But if uses -

```
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "query":"*Han Ol 453*",
            "fields":[
               "firstName",
               "lastName",
               "customerNo"
            ],
            "default_operator":"AND"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It results in no records, whereas it should match "Hanry Oliver 45354".
If and operator is removed, it results in all records having match han or ol or 453 whereas looking for query result having and-
*han* and *Ol* and *453*

Could someone help what query should be used in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `"query":"*Han Ol 453*"`, then the query string searches for `*Han` AND `Ol`AND `453*`

1. `*Han` --> will get no result
2. `Ol` --> will get no result
3. `453*` --> will get the result

Due to `453*` you are getting your result with the `OR` operator and not with the `AND` operator.

---

You need to modify your search query as

```
    {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Han* Ol* 453*",     // note this
      "fields": [
        "firstName",
        "lastName",
        "customerNo"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
      "analyze_wildcard":true
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67140182",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.0,
        "_source": {
          "firstName": "Hanry",
          "lastName": "Oliver",
          "customerNo": "45354"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @user1315086 please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me.
But I want to have exact match on top then others
like -
Hanry Oliver, 
M Hanry Oliver, 
Hanry Tran Oliver